# Ruby on Rails: NoMethodError in Users#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I know this is a common error and can be solved by doing the research (which I have done) however, I just cannot seem to figure out why my app is breaking when my code seems to be all in order. I'm hoping some extra eyes can get me past this.

The error I am getting is `NoMethodError in Users#show` `undefined method`[] for nil:NilClass`

Thanks in advance

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

         has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy


  def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    find_by_auth_hash(auth_hash) || create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
  end

  def self.find_by_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    where(
        provider:   auth_hash.provider,
        uid:        auth_hash.uid
        ).first
  end

  def self.create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    create(
        provider:         auth_hash.provider,
        uid:              auth_hash.uid,
        email:            auth_hash.info.email,
        name:             auth_hash.info.name,
        oauth_token:      auth_hash.credentials.token,
        oauth_expires_at: Time.at(auth_hash.credentials.expires_at)
        )
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end

  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    if encrypted_password.blank?
        update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
        super
    end
  end

  def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
  end

  def get_profile_info
    self.facebook.get_object("me")
  end

  def get_location
    h = get_profile_info["location"]
    h ["name"]
   end

  def get_books
    self.facebook.get_connection("me", "books")
  end

  def get_profile_picture
    self.facebook.get_picture(uid)
  end

end
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="media">
                <%= image_tag @user.get_profile_picture, class: "pull-left" %>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading"><%= @user.name %></h4>
                    from <%= @user.get_location %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="books">
                <% @user.get_books.each do |book| %>
                <p><%= book["name"] %></p>
                <% end %>
        </div></div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <% @users.posts.order("created_at DESC").each do |post| %>

            <div class="post">

                <h5><%= post.title %></h5>
                <p><%= post.content %></p>

                <span class="pull-right label label-info"><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago</span>

                <% if post.user == current_user %>
                <span class="pull-left"><%= link_to 'edit', edit_post_path(post), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %> <%= link_to 'destroy', post, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger", method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></span>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:show]
    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def show
    end

    private

    def set_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: You really ought to have a stack trace with line numbers. Is this in your production environment? If not, try the 'better errors' gem. It can save a whole load of hurt by giving you a much nicer error page with a live REPL.

Comment: Probably the set_user method doesn't find any user. Are you sure that your param 'id' is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I spy three candidates.

Two in the model

```
def get_location
    h = get_profile_info["location"] # <-- here
    h ["name"] # <-- here (most likely)
 end
```

One in the view

```
<% @user.get_books.each do |book| %>
    <p><%= book["name"] %></p> <!-- <-- here -->
<% end %>
```

The accessed Facebook data might be nil in one of those places.

Answer (score 1):

`Jesse` is right I think, but more importantly, there are several other issues to contend

---

**Variables**

You've provided what I presume to be your `show` view

The problem here is that you have calls to two instance variables:

```
<% @user.each ... %>

<% @users.posts.order("created_at DESC").each do |post| %>
```

Once you fix your `[]` problem, no doubt the reference to an undefined variable `@users` will be encountered. To remedy this, you either need to set your `@users` variable in your controller, or just reference `@user` (the only set variable)

---

**Errors**

The errors you've posted point to `[]` not being valid for the various data you've called.

`Jesse` made the right references (as to where the error will likely reside)

The "fix" will be either to make the array references conditional, or to ensure you have the data to back them up (IE putting the FB data into your database).

Here's how to determine the conditions:

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% if @user.get_books.any? %>
   <% @user.get_books.each do |book| %>
      <%= book["name"] %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= @user.get_location % if @user.get_location.any? %>
```